# Maven: use dependencies from repository when running command line app?

Tags: maven-2

I've used Maven to build my command line application. Now I'm going to distribute it as a jar file, and I need to handle the app's dependencies.

I don't want to include all dependencies in the jar file as described [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/customizing-sect-custom-packaged.html#customizing-sect-attaching-assembly).

The environment where my app will be run has Maven. I'd like Maven to run my jar looking at file `META-INF/groupId/artifactId/pom.xml` inside the package so it knows what the dependencies are and can find them in the repository.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

Include a main class in the jar that 1) extracts the pom to a temporary file, and 2) launches a new maven process using this file with the -f parameter and the goals [dependency:resolve](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html) and [dependency:build-classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html)

like this:

```
mvn -f /temp/tempfile.xml dependency:resolve dependency:build-classpath -DoutputFile=/temp/classpath.txt
```

then 3) reads the newly created classpath file and 4) launches a new java process using the new classpath file

```
java -cp yourjar.jar;<created classpath>
```

Your pom.xml will have to include all required repository information, of course

Comment: Great! Works for me with `-Dmdep.outputFile=...` (see UserProperty: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html#outputFile)

Comment: Option `-Dmdep.outputFile=...` had worked well, but only in `powershell` I was able to copy entire content for command `java -cp yourjar.jar;<created classpath>` and `powershell` had behaved differently. So wasn't succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

We can use, `maven-jar-plugin` instead, why because the classpath generated is not getting accommodated while copy paste with `java` command in command-line.

```
mvn -f /temp/tempfile.xml dependency:resolve dependency:build-classpath -DmdepoutputFile=/temp/classpath.txt
```

So wasn't able to succeed copying classpath.txt for the command,

```
java -cp yourjar.jar;<created classpath>
```

Mine is `spring-boot` application hence I have the following line with `BOOT-INF/lib`. For you it can be `WEB-INF/lib` in case of `.war` file or just `lib/` in case of `ant` build based projects.

```
<classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
<customClasspathLayout>BOOT-INF/lib/$${artifact.artifactId}-$${artifact.version}$${dashClassifier?}.$${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
```

`BOOT-INF`, comes up by `spring-boot:repackage` maven command and with the use of plugin,-`spring-boot-maven-plugin` that I have not Included here.

Please find `maven-jar-plugin` config here.

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>com.pakage.SampleApplication</mainClass>
                    <!--<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>-->                          
                    <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
                    <customClasspathLayout>BOOT-INF/lib/$${artifact.artifactId}-$${artifact.version}$${dashClassifier?}.$${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
                    <!--<customClasspathLayout>BOOT-INF/lib/$${artifact.groupIdPath}/$${artifact.artifactId}-$${artifact.version}$${dashClassifier?}.$${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>-->                      
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: It is not needed as because `WEB-INF/lib` `BOOT-INF/lib` are detected by default, if you have different setting, say you have libraries placed somewhere inside or somewhere else, then it helps. Accordingly you can configure it.

Comment: Actually I have similar problem as discussed here,- [Loading one configuration file in lib jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823597/java-loading-resources-class-class-getresource-vs-classname-class-getresource) with regards to that I am packing and exploring `MANIFEST.MF` configuration.

Comment: You need to add couple of dependencies first in order to work with `maven-jar-plugin`, those are `org.codehaus.plexus - plexus-utils` and `commons-lang`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven this feed helps in building jar file with dependencies, maven command needs to used is `mvn clean compile assembly:single`, that you can find it as part of the feed.