# How can I run a Java class inside a Maven artifact, automatically resolving dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

If I know the coordinates of an artifact, and a name of the class inside that artifact, can I make Maven run the class, *including all of its dependencies* on the Java classpath?

For example, suppose a coworker told me about a tool I can run, which is published to our internal Nexus with the artifact coordinates `example:cool-tools:1.0.0`.  I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895492/how-can-i-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line) to download the artifact.  Now, I know that the main class name is `example.Main`.  But if I just go to the artifact's download location and run `java -cp cool-tools-1.0.0.jar example.Main`, I get `NoClassDefFoundError`s for any dependencies of `cool-tools`.

I'm aware of the `maven-exec-plugin`, but as far as I can tell that's only for projects where you have the source.  Suppose I don't have access to the source, only the Nexus containing the tool (and all its dependencies).  Ideally, I'd do something like `mvn exec:exec -DmainArtifact='example:cool-tools:1.0.0' -DmainClass='example.Main'`, but I don't think the exec plugin is actually capable of this.

ETA: To be clear, I *do not* have a local project / POM.  I want to do this using *only* the command line, without writing a POM, if possible.

Comment: I strongly doubt you can achieve this without using a pom. It might be able to construct a temporary pom on the command line though, like in the following: echo "<pom content>" | mvn -f -

Comment: Not possible. The pom lists the dependencies, without it you'll never make maven build a classpath.

Comment: @Coderer Your assumption about the exec plugin is wrong. You can define the dependency in a separate pom where you define the dependencies and let exec plugin let run the class.

Comment: @khmarbaise OK, so I could make a throwaway POM and set it up to "depend" on `cool-tools`, then run the exec plugin.  Still a lot of work for what (I contend) *should* be possible in a one-liner.

Comment: @EngineerDollery - I guess what I meant was, Maven has all the information needed to calculate dependencies from the commandline -- grab the POM for the specified artifact, do dependency resolution, ensure all JARs are available, and add each to the CP.  Maybe this is something worth doing myself?

Comment: @Coderer - maven has non of the information -- the POM has the information, and you said that you do not have a local POM. Even if you grabbed the artifact's POM, you still wouldn't be able to use it because you don't have the source. You need to have a local/project POM of your own, that references the artifact you're interested in, as per the comment by khmarbaise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution for your task. But you can create a simple script to solve it:

- Download pom.xml of your tool from the repo.
- Download jar of your tool.
- Download all its dependencies.
- Run java against resolved libraries.

Command line:

```
> mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=<tool.group.id>:<tool.artifact.id>:<tool.version>:pom -DoutputDirectory=target
> mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=<tool.group.id>:<tool.artifact.id>:<tool.version> -DoutputDirectory=target
> mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -f target/<tool.artifact.id>-<tool.version>.pom -DoutputDirectory=target
> java -cp target/* <tool.main.class>
```

Directory ./target will contain your tool + all dependencies.

See details on [dependency:copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) and [dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) mojos.

**Edit**

As alternative, you can build classpath using libraries in the local repo by:

```
> mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeScope=runtime -f target/<tool.artifact.id>-<tool.version>.pom [-Dmdep.outputFile=/full/path/to/file]
```

See details on [build-classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) mojo.

Comment: Is it necessary to copy all those jars to "target"? Cannot the classpath be constructed directly from artefacts in the local maven repository?

Comment: I think `dependency:build-classpath` is a big chunk of the answer I was looking for.  I haven't had a chance to run it yet, but if it actually makes sure the dependencies are in the local repo first, that basically solves my problem.  I'll have to try it out!

Answer (score 1):

You could download the pom from the repository using `wget`, for instance. Then resolve the dependencies, and build the classpath exporting it to a file using Maven. Finally, execute with Java and the built classpath using something like bash backticks to use the content of the file.

Just like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945716/368544).

Answer (score 1):

For me the first anwer almost worked, but I needed to slightly adjust the script. In the end I came (on windows machine) to following solution:

```
> mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=<tool.group.id>:<tool.artifact.id>:<tool.version>:pom -DoutputDirectory=target
> mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=<tool.group.id>:<tool.artifact.id>:<tool.version> -DoutputDirectory=target
> mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -f target/<tool.artifact.id>-<tool.version>.pom -DoutputDirectory=target
> cd target
> java -cp target/*;<tool.artifact.id>-<tool.version>.jar <tool.main.class>
```

On Unix/Linux machine in the last command the semicolon ";" must be replaced with colon ":".
When input arguments must be provided, just put them in the last script line:

```
> java -cp target/*;<tool.artifact.id>-<tool.version>.jar <tool.main.class> arg1 arg2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use IDEs like Intellij idea which automatically resolve dependencies as u write them in your pom

Answer (score 0):

As it has been mentioned by others already there is no solution without creating an extra POM.

One solution could be to use the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) in this POM: *"This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar, including its dependencies"*

I think the [Executable JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) is close to that what you'd like to achieve.